# TIWApplet (VCL for the WEB) program and RAD Delphi XE

Tags: java, delphi, applet, delphi-xe, intraweb

I am trying to learn and program at the same time using RAD Studio Delphi XE. I am writing a mini (VCL for the web) program by utilizing TIWApplet. I have an applet that simply displays an image from a file on an applet. The java applet code compiled successfully and created a .class file. Then, I accordingly set the TIWapplet properties for the applet.

My VCL for the web program compiles and I am able to run it. However, whenever I open the browser to view the applet, I get an error stating, "Can't load appletImage.class files." But I am able to view the applet by creating a html file and opening it with a browser.

So, why can't TIWapplet open my applet?

I've searched the Internet up and down and even looked through their samples and demos. They are not helpful at all or that they don't even have anything related to (VCL for the Web) program.

Here is Java Applet code:

```
import java.applet.*; 
import java.awt.*; 

public class appletImage extends Applet{
  Image img;
  MediaTracker tr;
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
  tr = new MediaTracker(this);
  img = getImage(getCodeBase(), "testing.jpg");
  tr.addImage(img,0);
  g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
  } 
}
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<html>
  <head>
      <title>Arc Test (1.1)</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <h1>Arc Test (1.1)</h1>
      <hr>
      <applet code=appletImage.class width=400 height=400>
    alt="Your browser understands the &lt;APPLET&gt; tag but isn't running the applet, for some reason."
    Your browser is completely ignoring the &lt;APPLET&gt; tag!
      </applet>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to open the .class file directly in the browser?  That will not work. It makes sense that an `<applet>` tag inside an HTML file works, because that is the correct and only way to run Java classes in a browser.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, Since Delphi XE comes with an applet control (TIWapplet) to be able to run and display applet from your VCL application, I am assuming the compiler takes care to create the correct HTML code for the applet to be run from. In fact, compiler created html code is correct as I have verified it. However, applet doesn't load. You need to set TIWapplet control properties where it asks for your applet EXACT path and its EXACT name for both .class and .java. I have checked and they are EXACT and correct. So, I don't know why the applet has problem loading from my VCL application.

Comment: You need to talk to AToZed about that, as IntraWeb is an AToZed product, not an Embarcadero product.

Comment: I am sorry. I don't know if you are being sarcastic or just being honest. I am using what came with RAD Studio Delphi XE. I am pretty sure even if IntraWeb tools belong to third party, Embarcadero is not going to just blindly integrate them into their software and expect it work perfectly. This is simple. I placed the TIWApplet on the TIWForm and pointed it to a perfectly working java applet. it won't open the applet, but raise exception. What you are telling me is that if you bought a car with a faulty engine, call the engine manufacturer not the car dealership where you bought the car from.

Comment: @digitalanalog: Remy is being honest.  IntraWeb is a third party product that is bundled with Rad Studio.  http://www.atozed.com/intraweb/index.en.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to access the class file URL in the browser? If you enter its URL

```
http://localhost:port/yourapp/appletImage.class
```

the browser should open a dialog and prompt to download the Applet class file.

If the browser shows a 404 (or other resource not found) message, IntraWeb does not serve the class file over HTTP (or uses a different location for it).

Comment: No it didn't work. It said, "File Not Found." How do you locate the server's exact location? I searched and searched for clues and hints, but I simply can't locate the server's home or main folder that it expects files to be. I don't think its the folder where the server is compiled into exe file. Plus, the html page you see is created on the fly and therefore webpage that it sends to the client doesn't exists on the hardrive. Right?